# How to prevent replacing HTML elements when using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm matching HTML elements based on their `textContent`. Then surronding that match with `<strong>` tags:

```js
  const element = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
    .find(element => element.textContent.match('b'))
  
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('b', '<strong>$&</strong>')
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <br>
   <h3>blog</h3>
</a>
```

There's a problem, though. The code also matches HTML elements. So I get this:

```
<a href="#">
   &lt;<strong>b</strong>r&gt;
   <h3>blog</h3>
</a>
```

Instead of the desired result:

```
<a href="#">
   <br>
   <h3>blog</h3>
</a>
```

How to change my code so it doesn't match HTML elements? Only the text inside them?

Comment: Just... don't use `innerHTML`? You can find the actual text nodes in the `.childNodes` list (i.e. any node with `nodeType` 3) and then do surgery to replace one text node with as many text/dom/text triplets as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the children elements of your anchors and reset the HTML based on whether the textContent of the element contains "b".

Note: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will only find the first instance of the thing you're looking for. You need to explicitly iterate over all of the things.

> The `find()` method returns the value of the *first* element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];

function embolden(elements, str) {
  elements.forEach(element => {
    [...element.children].forEach(child => {
      if (child.textContent.includes('b')) {
        child.innerHTML = child.textContent.replace('b', '<strong>b</strong>');
      }
    });
  });
}

embolden(elements, 'b');
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <br>
  <p>blog</p>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <br>
  <p>blog</p>
  <p>Peterborough</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex: `/(?!<[^>]+)b(?![^<]+>)/g`

```js
const element = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
    .find(element => element.textContent.match('b'))

const string = "b";
const reg = new RegExp("(?!<[^>]+)" + string + "(?![^<]+>)", "g");
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(reg, '<mark>$&</mark>')
```

```css
mark
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <br>
   <h3 title="attributes are not affected bbbb">blog hover blog</h3>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use innerText instead of innerHTML to match. Insert the replaced values in the innerHTML

```js
const element = [...document.querySelectorAll('#example')]
    .find(element => element.textContent.match('b'))
  
  element.innerHTML = element.innerText.replace('b', '<strong>$&</strong>')
```

```html
<div id="example">
<div>This is some text.</div>
<br>
<div> This is part of the body </div>
</div>
```